# Cloudant Search field was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

I have the following Cloudant search index

```
"indexes": {
    "search-cloud": {
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "index": "function(doc) {

            if (doc.name) {
                index("keywords", doc.name);
                index("name", doc.name, {
                    "store": true,
                    "index": false
                });
            }

            if (doc.type === "file" && doc.keywords) {
                index("keywords", doc.keywords);
            }

        }"
    }
}
```

For some reason when I search for specific phrases, I get an error:

> Search failed: field "keywords" was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery (term=**FIRSTWORD**)

So If I search for **FIRSTWORD SECONDWORD**, it looks like I am getting an error on the first word.

**NOTE:** This does not happen to every search phrase I do.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

`doc.name` and `doc.keywords` are just string.

`doc.name` is usually something like *"2004/04/14 John Doe 1234 Document Folder"*

`doc.keywords` is usually something random like *"testing this again"*

And the reason why I am storing name and keywords under the keywords index is because I want anyone to be able to search keywords or name by just typing on string value. Let me know if this is not the best practice.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cloudant but does it really integrate with Elasticsearch?

Comment: @Val I misread and fixed the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the problem is that some of your documents contain a `keywords` field with string values, while other documents contain a `keywords` field with a different type, probably an array. I believe that this scenario would result in the error that you received. Can you double check that all of the values for your `keywords` fields are, in fact, strings?

Comment: You are absolutely right. For some reason some of my keywords got logged as integers for some reason. Thank you Bradley.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help you.